# Fans must like object before continue and get special content

Tags: facebook-like, forwarding, facebook-page

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Check if someone likes page before submit on own website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8711612/check-if-someone-likes-page-before-submit-on-own-website)

I'm a dj and i have my own fan page. I have a special landing page where people asked if they want to like the page for special content. After like they come on a special FAN TAB where i put some exclusive content.

No i have a new track made with a college DJ. We want to share the track! The idea is to put a like button (like to the other dj's page) on that fan tab. My fans must first hit the like button before they go to another page with the download link. And if it's possible the page must open in the same iframe i use!

Does anybody know if this is possible? I use the like generator ad the Facebook developers page, but i don't know how i get this work! Can someone help me?